# How to get the tags of a word tkinter text widget, from the word's index

Tags: python, tkinter

Let's say I have got the words index
starting `1.4` and ending `1.9`
from these 2 I need to get all the tags added to the word

Comment: You can use `.tag_names(index)` to get all tags related to `index`.

Comment: @acw1668 Can you show it with code I cannot make it work, please

Comment: Just `tags = text.tag_names('1.4')` if `text` is the `Text` widget.